# how to put 2 modifiers into a preview

Tags: swift, swiftui

having some trouble with the environment objects and was wondering how to put 2 modifiers in the preview to prevent the canvas from crashing

```
import SwiftUI

struct ArrayView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var data: DataExample
    @Binding var text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.data.textArray.append(self.text)
            }) {
                Text("Push onto array")
            }
            List(data.textArray, id: \.self) { string in
                Text(string)
            }
        }
//        .environmentObject(data)
    }

}

struct ArrayView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ArrayView(
            //how to put 2 modifiers
            text: .constant("String")
            .environmentObject(DataExample())
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Move the environment line outside the parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

Your preview struct should look like this.

```swift
struct ArrayView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ArrayView(text: .constant("String"))
            .environmentObject(DataExample())
    }
}
```

the `.constant()` in this example is setting the variable of text while the `.environmentObject()` is setting an environment variable that your `@EnvironmentObject` can read.